# java mail html format : how to render German umlaut characters

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using Jakarta mail for sending email.
The content of the mails are using html/text format. I do this as follow

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(smtpHost.getSession());
mimeMessage.setContent(text, ""text/html"");
```

But German Umlaut characters are not rendered correctly. These characters are converted into a question mark.

> Freundliche Gr�sse

How can I have German umlaut characters rendered correctly when the content of an email is in format text/html ?

Answer (score 1):

hello if you are writing the content you cant use th this https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

ü => `&uuml;`

if you don't you can "replace" the ü for example by `&uuml;` in the String.

Comment: I replaced ü with  &uuml;  ,  but that didn't solve the problem.  It's even worse. As of  &uuml;  nothing is rendered anymore.

Comment: is it in the html result if you print it ?

Comment: No,  everything behind  &uuml;  is not rendered.  So, the rendered text is :  Freundliche Gr

Comment: i don't know maby the code are escped... ? I dont have any infos to analyse the problem. could you make the test with the unicode ? with this : \u00fc instead of &uuml; By thwe way, you have 2 " in this line is it normal ? ""text/html""